# create Markers from Address stored in a remote server

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have to add some markers to the map in my android application.
I have to take all the addresses from my DB (that is in altervista) and create markers from these, but I don't know how to do.

Do I have to store the addresses in an Array, in an ArrayList or in a Map?

Can someone help me?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: what exactly do you receive from your database, is it a simple string (address), longitude and latitude or its an object holds some data ??

Comment: Improved English!!!

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a class(Activity) wich implements `OnMapReadyCallback`.

Something like this:

`public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback`

or you can just use the android studio assistant to create it:

[image]

In the Activity you need to retrieve the addresses from your db and save in an array. Later you need to convert the addresses no coordinates using for exemple GeoCoder library:   (Use a bucle to convert all and save it in a bidimensional array)

```
            try {
                    String locationName = String.valueOf(et.getText());
                    List<Address> listOfAddress = gc.getFromLocationName(locationName, 1);
                    Address address = listOfAddress.get(0);
                    double latitude = address.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = address.getLongitude();

                    coords= new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And latter you just need to add the markers in the map.

```
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coords).title("Marker name"));
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: You're wellcome.